# Hexo for multiple sites?

Tags: ejs, hexo

What's the best way of creating multiple Hexo sites? I wanted to redo all of my sites (I have around 10 sites in total) would I just run:

```
$ hexo init site1
$ hexo init site2
$ hexo init site3
```

... and so on? Is there a better way of dealing with multiple sites?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Hexo you may have multiple sites (with multiple themes on they) and use same plugins with same Hexo version in single root Hexo dir (no need to duplicate main `node_modules` directory).

To do this, need to use commands with [alternate configuration](https://hexo.io/docs/configuration.html#Using-an-Alternate-Config) specified.

1. Init Hexo site.
2. Create empty `site1.yml` file and paste all content from main Hexo `_config.yml`.
3. Create empty `site2.yml` file and paste all content from main Hexo `_config.yml`.
4. All this 3 files must be in Hexo root directory. And then specify needed configuration:

   ```
   $ hexo clean --config site1.yml && hexo g --config site1.yml
   $ hexo clean --config site2.yml && hexo g --config site2.yml

   $ hexo s --config site1.yml
   $ hexo d --config site1.yml
   ```

Input `hexo -h` for advanced info.

Answer (score -1):

```
d:/hexo1
d:/hexo3
d:/hexo2
```

create multiple directory and `d:/hexo2> hexo init`